# How to extract an email address from within an iframe using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, iframe, automation

I'm automating a task with Selenium in Python to extract an email address and phone number that is displayed within a modal window. The modal content is inside an iframe, and I'm having trouble retrieving the email address text.

[Link for the website](https://fscm.teamworks.georgia.gov/psc/supp/SUPPLIER/ERP/c/SCP_PUBLIC_MENU_FL.SCP_PUB_BID_CMP_FL.GBL?&)

[image: Website Image]

```
contact_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SCP_COSP_WK_FL_IMAGE_1$0"]')
            contact_button.click()
            time.sleep(8)
            email_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SCP_P_AUCDTL_VW_EMAILID"]'))
            )
            email_address = email_element.text.strip()

            print(email_address)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is we need to consider an iframe as separate page, move to the page, and then try to scrape data from it.
This can be achieved by using `switch_to.frame` in the `webdriver` module.
Here is the link for docs for your reference: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/

Here is the code that I have tested with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import Byfrom selenium.webdriver.support.ui 
import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support 
import expected_conditions as ec
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())  
url = "https://fscm.teamworks.georgia.gov/psc/supp/SUPPLIER/ERP/c/SCP_PUBLIC_MENU_FL.SCP_PUB_BID_CMP_FL.GBL"

driver.get(url)
event_id = "SCP_PUB_AUC_VW$0_row_0"
events = driver.find_element(By.ID,event_id)
events.click()

button_class = '//*[@id="win0divSCP_COSP_WK_FL_IMAGE_1$0"]'

# Waiting for button to be visible and the clicking it
button_element = wait(driver,10).until(
    ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,button_class)))
button_element.click()

frame_id = "ptModFrame_0"
contact_section = "PT_MID_SECTION"
# here we are waiting for the frame to be visible and then we need to switch 
# from our current page to the frame so that we can extract data from the frame 
wait(driver,10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,frame_id)))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_id)

contact_details = driver.find_element(By.ID,contact_section)
print(contact_details.text)
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID '#pt_pageinfo' is not visible here. Maybe it could be country specific. So I couldn't check whether my code is working. Check my code and modify according to your requirement(like IFrame ID etc.,). [My Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/kk12KvD)

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec


dr_path = '/path/to/chromedriver'
dr = wd.Chrome(executable_path=dr_path)
url = 'https://fscm.teamworks.georgia.gov/psc/supp/SUPPLIER/ERP/c/SCP_PUBLIC_MENU_FL.SCP_PUB_BID_CMP_FL.GBL'
dr.get(url)
```

It asked login details when I clicked the website link first time. Use the following if it requires logging. **Modify url in the previous code accordingly.** After logging in, once again you've to visit go to the page with above link

```
'''
Locate the username and password input fields.(replace `username` and `password` with the actual names/IDs)
Enter your credentials and Submit the login form
'''
uname = dr.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
pw = dr.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
uname.send_keys('your_username')
pw.send_keys('your_password')
pw.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Wait for the login to complete (you may have to customize condition)
wait(dr, 10).until(ec.url_contains('dashboard'))
```

And you can extract data inside the iframe with the following methods.

```
#Switch to the iframe and extract email addresses(Replace with the actual name/ID of the iframe)
ifID = 'iframe_id_or_name'  
dr.switch_to.frame(ifID)

# locate the email addresses (replace 'email' with the actual selector)
emailtags = dr.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'email')
for x in emailtags:print(x.text)
dr.switch_to.default_content()
dr.quit()
```